# Function equal to its own arclength.

Tags: calculus, analysis, arc-length

Does there exist a differentiable function $f(x)$ such that

$$f(x) = \int_0^x \sqrt{1+[f'(t)]^2}dt?$$

I'm quite interested in finding if there is such a function, as its value at any point $t$ would be the length of the curve from $x=0$ to $x=t$ and I think such a function must necessarily be beautiful in some way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If it exists it’ll satisfy $(f’)^2 = 1 + (f’)^2$ if that helps.

Comment: The arc length of $f(x) = 0$ from $x=0$ to $x=t$ is given by $t$, not $0$.

Comment: No.  There is no such function.

Comment: Slightly related and possibly interesting to the OP: [$f^\prime=$arclength](https://youtu.be/zf8y0QhG_h8).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose there was such a function $f$. Fix an $x > 0$. Since the arclength of $f$ between $0$ and $x$ is at least the length of the straight line between $(0,f(0)) = (0,0)$ and $(x,f(x))$, we have $$f(x) = \int_0^x\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2}\,dt \ge \sqrt{x^2+f(x)^2} > f(x),$$ a contradiction. Thus, no such function $f$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such function. If there was, you could take the $x$-derivative of both sides, then square both sides, then you'd obtain $0=1$. That's wrong, therefore no such function exists.